# Python import warning and no response from server

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on an app and when I run the API.py file in powershell, I get this output

```
Bottle v0.12.19 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8085/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:914: ImportWarning: _ImportRedirect.find_spec() not found; falling back to find_module()
```

As you can see the server starts at 0.0.0.0:8085 and then I get an import warning.

When I put in the http://0.0.0.0:8085/ I get "The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8085/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address." And none of front end calls (for example to log in to the app) get errors.

I have a feeling its due to the import warning but I'm not sure.

Here are my imports

```
import json

from bottle import app, get, hook, post, route, run, request, response
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from unqlite import UnQLite
from buildDB import BuildDB
from encrypt_passwords import encrypt_passwords
```

When I Ctrl+C the python server I also get this after the import warning.

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bottle.py:3139: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=468, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 8085)>
  pass
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: Are you running the bottle server and requesting the page on the same computer?

Comment: Yeah, I am. Isn't that how its supposed to be?

Comment: Is bottle running directly on your computer, or is it inside a docker container/virtual environment?

Comment: Directly, I don't use docker.

Comment: Hmm.  Can you try using `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0` in the web request?

Comment: Mmm, yes I'm now seeing requests in powershell using localhost. all of my fetches are failing still from the frontend still though

Comment: Just ensure that you grants all users the permission to run the file API.py (app.py or main.py or whatever the launcher is) before you actually run it. 

$ chmod a+x API.py 
$ python API.py

Answer (score 0):

I had to change a base url variable i had in one of my python scripts to go from 0.0.0.0 to http://localhost:8085 server is now working!